# Ejecutar automaticamente un script php en el servidor

Tags: php, servidor, script, ejecutar, ticket

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de tickets virtuales para el hospital de mi ciudad, la idea es que podrán agendar una cita medica.

Mi tabla de citas solo tiene los campos: Medico, Paciente, Hospital, Hora, NroFicha, Estado

Lo que pasa es que cada día se habilitaran nuevas fichas en el sistema, para un nuevo día, por lo que las anteriores deben desactivarse, los médicos no deben apretar ningún botón ni habrá una interface para desactivar las fichas.

Lo que necesito es que de **manera automática, en el servidor** una vez lleguen a las 23:59 se ejecute un archivo que **cambie el Estado** de todas las citas **anteriores a esa hora** de **Activo a Inactivo**

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de que el script se ejecute directo en el servidor a una hora determinada.

Comment: Depende del sistema operativo del servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Si es posible con `cron`.

> cron es un administrador regular de procesos en segundo plano que ejecuta procesos o guiones a intervalos regulares (por ejemplo, cada minuto, día, semana o mes). Los procesos que deben ejecutarse y la hora a la que deben hacerlo se especifican en el archivo crontab.

Para poder utilizar `cron` debes de tener acceso a la terminal de servidor.
[Este](https://github.com/pschlan/cron-job.org) es su repositorio de github